# Problem inserting .pdf_tex file from Inkscape

Tags: graphics, svg, inkscape

I am trying to insert an image from Inkscape. 
I saved it as a pdf, checking the PDF + Latex option.
Inside my Latex file, I wrote the following code :

```
\begin{figure}  
  \centering  
  \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}  
  \input{topo4serv.pdf_tex}  
\end{figure}
```

but when i try to compile using pdflatex, it gives me the following error message:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.  

--- TeX said ---  
<argument> \includegraphics  
                            [width=\unitlength ]{topo4serv.pdf}
l.52 ...raphics[width=\unitlength]{topo4serv.pdf}}
                                                   %
```

In the output pdf file the text of the svg file is there but not the shapes...
If someone has an answer i would be very grateful.

Comment: First time I am seeing something like `topo4serv.pdf_tex`. I would rather say `\includegraphics{topo4serv.pdf}`

Comment: @azetina Usage seems correct as it is stated here: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape

Comment: It is correct to use `\input{file.pdf_tex}`. If you open that file, it has instructions for its usage. Like egreg said, you need to have `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble for this to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\includegraphics`is giving error because it is not defined, which means you need to `\usepackage{graphicx}` on document's preamble