# Can't find pdf_tex from inkscape

Tags: graphics, inkscape

I'm experiencing the same issue as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61676/problem-inserting-pdf-tex-file-from-inkscape): I want to make use of "tex in inkscape" technology.

Here's a tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{200pt}
  \input{drawing.pdf_tex}
  \caption{Double pendulum}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here's a pdf_tex:

```
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined
    \setlength{\unitlength}{311.07356567pt}
  \else
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}
  \fi
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined
  \makeatother
  \begin{picture}(1,0.59438645)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{drawing.pdf}}%
    \put(0.48568235,0.40805542){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$\ell_1$}}}%
    \put(0.67084755,0.16631196){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$\ell_2$}}}%
    \put(0.71199538,0.04029675){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$m_2$}}}%
    \put(0.55254756,0.27175325){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$m_1$}}}%
    \put(0.52940191,0.0763011){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$\theta_2$}}}%
    \put(0.42138888,0.28204021){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$\theta_1$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

I get the error:

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'drawing.pdf'.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.46 ...egraphics[width=\unitlength]{drawing.pdf}}
                                                  %
?
```

so it looks like my tex looks for a `drawing.pdf` instead of `drawing.pdf_tex`.

I'm using `TeX Live 2012/Debian`.

Comment: `\input{drawing.pdf_tex}` found `drawing.pdf_tex` but then as that was processed it got to `\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{drawing.pdf}` which requires the file `drawing.pdf` which is presumably supposed to have been made by inkscape?

Comment: Oh I see -- so I need both files! Make it an answer -- so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\input{drawing.pdf_tex}` found `drawing.pdf_tex` but then as that was processed it got to

```
\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{drawing.pdf}
```

which requires the file `drawing.pdf` which is presumably supposed to have been made by inkscape?