# figures not appearing from pdf

Tags: graphics, floats, inkscape

I've been drawing figures in inkscape, labeling with TeX syntax inside inkscape, saving as pdf, having inkscape build me a pdf_tex file and using TeXShop to write the TeX file which calls the figure as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{graphicx, transparent, color}
\usepackage{media9}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\linespread{1}
\theoremstyle{plain}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem*{rmk}{Remark}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark.]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{eg}{Example}
\newtheorem{egs}{Examples}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] \centering \def\svgwidth{250pt} \input{figure3o4.pdf_tex} 
 \caption{The map from $\widetilde {\mathcal P}$ to the suspension of 4 points.  
   Each labeled edge corresponds to the various heights for the corresponding apex 
   vertex.}
\label{pgraph}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h] \centering \def\svgwidth{250pt} \input{7o10ii.pdf_tex} 
  \caption{The map from $\widetilde {\mathcal P}$ to the suspension 
     of 4 points.  Each labeled edge corresponds to the various heights for the 
     corresponding apex vertex.}
\label{pgraph}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

This has worked for me many times, but today I'm finding that the figures that I create have pieces missing from the graphics after I compile, but *only when I view the pdf in Preview, Safari, or TeXshop*.  When I view in chrome or the viewer in TeXworks, the image appears totally fine.

This is strange, I didn't think pdf's were so unstable.  Has anyone experienced anything like this or might suggest what the problem is?

Comment: I have reason to believe it has something to do with where it thinks the image is, on the page.  My most recent test is a graphic of a lot of scribbles and the very top of those scribbles are showing up in the final TeX'd pdf.

Comment: This story is getting more bizarre.  Some viewers (chrome, texworks) show the pdf exactly as it should be without any cropping.  Some (preview, safari) show the image cropped with only white where the image should be.  I had no idea pdf's could be so insecure.  What's going on?

Comment: To attract more attention, I'd suggest adding a _complete_ [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Right now we have no idea which document class or packages are in use.

Comment: @Andrew Did you check this one ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61676/problem-inserting-pdf-tex-file-from-inkscape

Comment: @PaulGessler Okay, thanks, I've included the preamble I use.  Isn't a complete minimal working example one that includes my image source files?  There's no way to upload them, is there?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Please make your code _minimal_. Or add the `everything-but-the-kitchen-sink` package.

Comment: I am not sure if this is in any way related, but since an mac update a couple of weeks ago, preview seems to have problems with the bounding boxes of some .pdfs now. In my case it displays way to much space around the actual image whereas with adobe it displays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If different PDF viewers show different things, they are probably broken. Check with Adobe's reader (that one should be the gold standard), check with tools that do *only* PDF (or document) viewing, like on Linux `xpdf(1)` or `evince(1)`. See what your (PDF) printer prints.

You might want to check if newer versions of the tools are available, and if they still misbehave.

Make a minimal example (LaTeX et al source, generated PDF) and report any bugs as appropiate.

Comment: per the 1st suggestion, the differences are not just appearing on my version, but on that of my adviser as well as my phone.  I'm sure the issue is with inkscape, but I've reinstalled and no change.